# GoalSeek looping through columns

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to loop through columns and use the GoalSeek function on each of the cells required.

I have a button which, when clicked, runs 'GoalSeek1'.

When I run click the button, it runs correctly up until the For loop and the I get the error: "Run-time error '13':  Type mismatch".

The data starts in column E (Column 5).

Row 234 is where the results are.
Row 240 is where the target results are.
Row 164 is where the changed results should be.

Data example:

```
Cell E164 = 60 
Cell E234 = 7 (Formula based result) 
Cell E240 = 8
```

When I use the manual GoalSeek, I set E234 as the 'Set Cell', 'to Value' as 8 and 'By Changing Cell' to E164, E164 updates to 69.

*Updated code as requested*

```
Private Sub GoalSeek1()
    'For testing purposes only
    MsgBox "GoalSeek1"
    
    'Defining variable i
    Dim i As Integer
    'Defining column count. Cell holds a number value
    Dim controlCell As Integer
    controlCell = Range("C14")
    
        'Looping through column 5 to target of (column 5 + r)
        For i = 5 To (5 + controlCell)
            Cells(234, Columns(i)).GoalSeek Goal:=Cells(240, Columns(i)), ChangingCells:=Cells(164, Columns(i))
        Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Not tested but as far as I know, when you use `Cells` you must specify always numbers: first would be the row number and second argument would be the column number. So when you do `"234"` you are passing a text, not a number. Besides, if `234` is the row number, it should be the first argument. Probably you need something like `Cells(234, Columns(i))` Same for the rest of the code where you use `Cells`.

Comment: Thanks for that @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns.  I've now changed the order around.  Note: I am still getting the Type Mismatch error.

Comment: Can you edit your question and update with the new code? Also, a data example and expected output would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Please, try:

```
Private Sub GoalSeek1()
'For testing purposes only
MsgBox "GoalSeek1"

'Defining variable i
Dim i As Integer
'Defining column count. Cell holds a number value
Dim controlCell As Integer
controlCell = Range("C14").Value

'Looping through column 5 to target of (column 5 + r)
For i = 5 To (5 + controlCell)
    Cells(234, i).GoalSeek Cells(240, i).Value, Cells(164, i)
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I tried this and get a run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

Comment: @KeithK what line does arise the error?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise you changed 'ChangingCells' to just 'Cells'.  The code the error appears on is Cells(234, i).GoalSeek Cells(240, i).Value, Cells(164, i) but the new error with this line is "Reference isn't valid"

Comment: I've added "" around each of the i's and it runs but doesn't seem to update anything, so will do some testing.

Comment: If the error says `Reference isn't valid` means the setup of your GoalSeek is not correct. It's not a problem of code, it's more a setup problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the help on here and a further search online.  I found the answer that I was looking for:

```
Private Sub GoalSeek1()

Dim k As Long
Dim ResultCell As Range
Dim ChangingCell As Range
Dim TargetFTE As Range

Dim controlCell As Integer
controlCell = Range("C14").Value

    For k = 5 To (5 + controlCell)
        Set ResultCell = Cells(234, k)
        Set TargetFTE = Cells(240, k)
        Set ChangingCell = Cells(164, k)
        ResultCell.GoalSeek TargetFTE, ChangingCell

    Next k

End Sub
```